# Can anyone do a many to many relationship between two django models only with the ForeignKey?

Tags: django, foreign-keys, models

I have two Django models, lets say an `Album` and a `Song` Model.

I have a `ForeignKey` field to my `Song` model so I can correlate multiple songs to an `Album` (many to one relationship). If I don't change anything in my models and leave them as they are can I succeed a many to many relationship (same song to different albums and vise versa) if I change the way that my database stores my data (normalize, denormalize etc)?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can't, that's the reason for intermediate tables and the [ManyToMany relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) that Django supports.

In fact, considering that your models are as follows:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    album = FK(Album)

class Album(models.Model):
    attributes ...
```

You have enough representational power to store **several songs** for **one album**. You ***Can't have*** multiple albums per song.

Putting the `ForeignKey` in the `Album` class would only worsen things, as you can have several albums per song, and each album then belongs to a single song ! (that's definitely wrong right ?)

So what you want is a [ManyToMany relationship](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/), between an `Album` and a `Song`, represented like the following:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    attributes ...

class Album(models.Model):
    songs = models.ManyToManyField(Song)
```

This way, each `Song` belongs to several `Album`s and vice versa, as you want them to.

Comment: I agree with you, but what if I change the schema of my database? Maybe then I could  succeed a many to many relationship with only the ForeignKey Field

Comment: @jimao what does it mean, *change the schema of my database* ? If it means changing the FK to M2M then yes, but I don't see any changes helping you to represent such relationship with a single FK.

Comment: Something like normalize and denormalize techniques in database

Comment: DB normalization or denormalization is done with the purpose of reducing the amount of table joins and relationship lookups, in return for increasing redundancy, or vice versa. They don't have anything to do with the need for M2Ms or FKs. You have an *Inherent many to many relationship* between your entities and you have to preserve that.

Comment: ok thanks a lot for your help @SpiXel I think that i understood the concept of o2m and m2m in django